# template doesn't update after resetting everything

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom element that adds items to a container. I have a "close" functionality that closes the container and clears the items so the user can start adding new ones. This works great for adding stuff and closing, but when I try to add new items after the custom element has been closed, the template doesn't seem to update like I want it to.

Here's my custom element:

```
<template>
    <div id="item-wrapper">
        <div id="item-header">
            <div id="item-title">${itemTitle}</div>
            <div id="item-close" click.trigger="close($event)">X</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none;">${itemDataConveyor.getItems()}</div>
        <div repeat.for="item of itemDataConveyor.getItems()" class="item-container">
            ${item}
        </div>            
    </div>
</template>
```

And some parts of the JS:

```
constructor(itemDataConveyor) {
        this.itemDataConveyor = itemDataConveyor;

}

close(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('before' + this.itemDataConveyor.getItems());
    this.itemDataConveyor.clear();
    console.log('after' + this.itemDataConveyor.getItems());
    $('#item-wrapper').hide();
}
```

if I add say 3 items and then close the custom element I get the output:

```
before [item1],[item2],[item3]
after
```

I've checked through developer console debug that the items gets cleared properly and added properly, but the template doesn't delete the items and it doesn't add any new ones after `close(event)` has been called.

the hidden div doesn't change after close either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that when you call `itemDataConveyor.getItems()` inside your repeater:

```
<div repeat.for="item of itemDataConveyor.getItems()" class="item-container">
    ${item}
</div>
```

you are iterating through a copy of items. So deleting all items won't change what has been rendered.

Maybe try something like this:

```
<div repeat.for="item of items" class="item-container">
    ${item}
</div>
```

and in your view model:

```
constructor(itemDataConveyor) {
    this.itemDataConveyor = itemDataConveyor;
    this.items = this.itemDataConveyor.getItems();
}

close(event){
    this.itemDataConveyor.clear();
    this.items = this.itemDataConveyor.getItems();
    $('#item-wrapper').hide();
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try it in a few hours and report back ;) ty